# find the coordinates of the point in planes?

Tags: geometry

Find the coordinates of the point in $\mathbb{R}^3$
 which is the reflection of the
point $(1, 2, 4)\quad$ with respect to the plane $x + y + z = 1.$

I was trying this question, but I could not get it. I was trying to solve by taking midpoint as $x/2 + 1/2 =1,\quad$
I got the value of x coordinates $= 1,\quad$    similarly I got value of of $y= 0$ and $z= -2.\quad$    coordinates is $(1,0,-2).\quad$
I don't have any hint or any idea to solve this problem.
If anybody help me, I would be very thankful to him.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1. Get the line through the point which is perpendicular to the plane. (It is $r:(x,y,z)=(1,2,4)+t(1,1,1).$)
2. Get the intersection point of the line and the plane. (That is, $1+t+2+t+4+t=1\implies t=-2.$ So, the point is $M(-1,0,2).$)
3. The point above is the midpoint of the segment given by the original point and its reflection. (Thus, the reflection point $P'$ of $P(1,2,4)$ with respect to the plane satisfies $\vec{PM}=\vec{MP'}.$ In other words, $\vec{OP'}=\vec{OP}+2\vec{PM}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Let the reflection point be $X(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

The equation of the line that passes through the point $A(1,2,4)$ and is perpendicular to the plane $x+y+z-1=0$ is: 
$$\frac{x-1}{1}=\frac{y-2}{1}=\frac{z-4}{1}.$$
The line intersects the plane at the point:
$$x+y+z-1=0 \Rightarrow x+(x+1)+(x+3)-1=0 \Rightarrow B(x,y,z)=B(-1,0,2).$$
The point $B$ is the midpoint of $A$ and $X$:
$$\frac{1+x_0}{2}=-1 \Rightarrow x_0=-3,$$
$$\frac{2+y_0}{2}=0 \Rightarrow y_0=-2,$$
$$\frac{4+z_0}{2}=2 \Rightarrow z_0=0.$$

Comment: how u take  x+ x+1 + x + 3 im  not getting this lines @ farruhota

Comment: Since the line $x-1=y-2=z-4$ intersects the plane $x+y+z-1=0$, you substitute $y=x+1, z=x+3$ into the plane equation to find the common point.

Comment: thanks now i got it @ farruhota

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(1+t,2+t,4+t)$ be out point.

Thus, $$\frac{|1+t+2+t+4+t-1|}{\sqrt3}=\frac{|1+2+4-1|}{\sqrt3}$$ or
$$|3t+6|=6,$$
which gives $t=0$, which was already, or $t=-4$, which gives the answer:
$$(-3,-2,0)$$

Comment: 'out' - typo? Perhaps add an explanation for why the point is in the form $(1+t,2+t,4+t)$?

Comment: @Shuri2060 Because vector normal of our plain is $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: how u take divide  root 3 @ michael rozenberh

Comment: @lomber lego It's $\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an optimal way, but you can do this using the normal line to the plane passing through this point. We know that such a line is given by 
$$(x(t),y(t),z(t))= (x_0+t,y_0+t,z_0+t).$$
If we want $(1,2,4)$ to be parametrized at $t=1$, we can solve 
$$ x(1)=1+x_0=1\implies x_0=0$$
$$ y(1)=y_0+1=2\implies y_0=1$$
$$ z(1)=z_0+1=4\implies z_0=3.$$
So, the desired line is given by 
$$ (x(t),y(t),z(t))=(t,1+t,3+t).$$
Then, the reflected point is at $t=-1$, so we have that 
$$ p=(x(-1),y(-1),z(-1))=(-1,0,2).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$A=(1,2,4) $$
$$B=(x,y,z) $$
$\vec {AB}$ is parallel to normal vector of the plane $(1,1,1) $
thus
$$x-1=y-2=z-4$$

the middle of $[A,B] $ is in the plane
so
$$x+1+y+2+z+4=2$$

hence
$$x+1+x+1+2+x+3+4=2$$
and the point we look for is

> $$(x,y,z)=(-3,-2,0) $$